# Draggable Button not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm new in here. Here is the problem, currently I create a website and referred draggable button from [Here](https://codepen.io/zessx/pen/mErQga?q=drag%20button&limit=all&type=type-pens). Every browser work fine except IE11, I tried to console but did not see any problem there. Then, I put the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">` also not working. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```js
var drag1   = document.querySelector('.drag1'),
    path1   = document.querySelector('.drag--path1'),
    button1 = document.querySelector('.drag--button1'),
    shift1  = button1.getAttribute('cx'),
    pathR1  = path1.getBoundingClientRect();

function startDrag1(event) {
  drag1.classList.add('dragging');  
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', updateDrag1);
}

function updateDrag1(event) {
  // On récupère les coordonnées de la souris
  var x = event.pageX || event.clientX;
  // On fixe des limites sur X, en se basant sur la taille du path
  x = Math.max(x, pathR1.left);
  x = Math.min(x, pathR1.left + pathR1.width);
  x -= pathR1.left;
  // On transforme cet avancement en longeur d'arc
  var l = x * path1.getTotalLength() / pathR1.width;
  // On récupère le point de l'arc à cet avancement
  var point = path1.getPointAtLength(l);
  // On fixe les mêmes coordonnées au bouton
  button1.setAttribute('cx', point.x);
  button1.setAttribute('cy', point.y);
}

function stopDrag1(event) {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', updateDrag1);
  drag1.classList.remove('dragging');
  var cx = parseFloat(button1.getAttribute('cx')),
      point = path1.getPointAtLength(0);
  // On vérifie si on a dépassé 60% d'avancement
  if (100 * (cx - shift1) / pathR1.width > 60) {
    // Si oui, on défini le point de chute à la fin du path
    point = path1.getPointAtLength(path1.getTotalLength());
    button1.setAttribute('cx', point.x);
    button1.setAttribute('cy', point.y);
    finishDrag1();
  } else {
    // Si non, on défini le point de chute au début du path
    point = path1.getPointAtLength(0);
    button1.setAttribute('cx', point.x);
    button1.setAttribute('cy', point.y);
  }
}

function finishDrag1() {
  // On a emmené le bouton au bout, on désactive les événements
  drag1.classList.add('finished');
  window.open("http://www.google.com", "_blank");
  var point = path1.getPointAtLength(0);
  button1.setAttribute("cx", point.x);
  button1.setAttribute("cy", point.y);
  drag1.classList.add('dragagain');
  
}

button1.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag1);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag1);
document.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDrag1);
```

Comment: Welcome, you will need to provide us with your code to make it possible to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ MateuszJuruś and @ T.J.Crowder, thanks for the quick response! I just updated my post. Thanks!